# Set JTree in one java class file from second java class file - Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two java class under same package 1. mrbpdf.java and FileTreeDemo.java, I want set the JTree functionalities from FileTreeDemo.java to mrbpdf.java JTree, since I am newbie! finding difficulties to do it. Please give me directions, thanks, if my question is unclear please comment it, will change it accordingly.

Basically I want show the root (for example c:/ ) file directory in mrbpdf.java;

mrbpdf.java

```
public class mrbpdf {

private JFrame frmViperManufacturingRecord;
private JTextField txtText; //declearing here for global variable

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mrbpdf window = new mrbpdf();
                window.frmViperManufacturingRecord.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public mrbpdf() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
public void initialize() {
    frmViperManufacturingRecord = new JFrame();
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.setTitle("Manufacturing Record Book");
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.setBounds(100, 100, 1026, 702);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnGeneratePdfHeader = new JButton("Generate PDF Header");
    btnGeneratePdfHeader.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to viper");
            txtText.setText("Hi User....");
        }
    });
    btnGeneratePdfHeader.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 12));
    btnGeneratePdfHeader.setBounds(786, 183, 156, 23);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(btnGeneratePdfHeader);

    txtText = new JTextField();
    txtText.setText("text1");
    txtText.setBounds(678, 182, 98, 23);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(txtText);
    txtText.setColumns(10);


    JTree tree = new JTree();
    tree.setBounds(10, 11, 304, 624);
    //tree.setModel("FileTreeDemo");
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tree);


    frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(tree);
}
}
```

FileTreeDemo.java

```
public class FileTreeDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File root;
    if (args.length > 0) root = new File(args[0]);
    else root = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));

    FileTreeModel model = new FileTreeModel(root);

JTree tree = new JTree();
tree.setModel(model);

// The JTree can get big, so allow it to scroll.
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tree);

// Display it all in a window and make the window appear
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileTreeDemo");
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollpane, "Center");
frame.setSize(400,600);
frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class FileTreeModel implements TreeModel {
  // We specify the root directory when we create the model.
  protected File root;
   public FileTreeModel(File root) { this.root = root; }

  // The model knows how to return the root object of the tree
  public Object getRoot() { return root; }

 // Tell JTree whether an object in the tree is a leaf or not
 public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {  return ((File)node).isFile(); }

 // Tell JTree how many children a node has
 public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
   String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
   if (children == null) return 0;
   return children.length;
  }

  public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
     String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
     if ((children == null) || (index >= children.length)) return null;
     return new File((File) parent, children[index]);
   }

   public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
     String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
     if (children == null) return -1;
     String childname = ((File)child).getName();
    for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
     if (childname.equals(children[i])) return i;
    }
   return -1;
  }

  public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newvalue) {}

   public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}
   public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the FileTreeModel tree model in the mrbpdf class, you can use this code in the mrbpdf.initialize method:

```
//JTree tree = new JTree();

File root = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
FileTreeModel model = new FileTreeModel(root);
JTree tree = new JTree(model);
```

To add scrolling as well, this code could help you (in the same method as above):

```
//tree.setBounds(10, 11, 304, 624);
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tree);
scrollpane.setBounds(10, 11, 304, 624);

//frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(tree);
frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(scrollpane);
```

---

**Edit** - to support multiple roots, you could use a different tree model, like for example:

```
class MultipleDirectoriesTreeModel implements TreeModel {
    protected List<File> roots;

    public MultipleDirectoriesTreeModel(File... roots) {
        this.roots = Arrays.asList(roots);
    }

    public Object getRoot() { return this; }

    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
        return node instanceof File && ((File)node).isFile();
    }

    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
        if (parent == this)
            return roots.size();
        else {
            String[] children = ((File) parent).list();
            if (children == null)
                return 0;
            return children.length;
        }
    }

    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        if (parent == this)
            return index >= 0 && index < roots.size() ? roots.get(index) : null;
        else {
            String[] children = ((File) parent).list();
            if ((children == null) || (index >= children.length))
                return null;
            return new File((File) parent, children[index]);
        }
    }

    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        String childname = ((File) child).getName();
        if (parent == this) {
            for (int rootIndex = 0; rootIndex < roots.size(); rootIndex++)
                if (childname.equals(roots.get(rootIndex).getName()))
                    return rootIndex;
            return -1;
        } else {
            String[] children = ((File) parent).list();
            if (children == null)
                return -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                if (childname.equals(children[i]))
                    return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "My Computer";
    }

    public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newvalue) {}
    public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}
    public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}
}
```

This tree model could be initialized like this:

```
MultipleDirectoriesTreeModel model
    = new MultipleDirectoriesTreeModel(new File("C:\\"), new File("D:\\"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Freek de Bruijn, its worked, now I got file directory from FileTreeDemo.java to mrbpdf.java, so elegantly you have done. Thanks again

Comment: Hi @Freek de Bruijn, now the file structure shows only from the c:/ , how to get entire file directory for [example](http://i.imgur.com/jUdte6I.png):- from My computer to all drives, thanks

Comment: Hi @Java.beginner, if you want the tree to support multiple root directories (C:\, D:\, etc.), you can modify the FileTreeModel  class. You can use a list of root directories (instead of a single root) and add a new tree root object "My computer". The next step is to modify the five get/is methods (of the TreeModel interface). If you get started with that and put your modified code in your question, I can help you a bit (if needed). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Freek de Bruijn, if I get stuck will post new question and intimate to you, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Freek de Bruijn, have posted the question to get the multiple root [directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128165/get-multiple-root-directories-on-jtree-to-select-the-leaf-swing), after a long struggle am requesting, thanks

Comment: HI @Freek de Bruijn, did you get a time to see my request please.

Comment: Hi @Freek de Bruijn, thank you so much for your update, will work on it and get back to you with results, thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: Hi @Freek de Bruijn, have posted the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318486/desktop-view-in-jtree-swing) please find time give some directions on this, thank you so much.

Comment: *"to support multiple roots, you could use a different tree model"* Agreed, but I'd use `DefaultTreeModel` instead, wrapping each file as a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` user object. This way you can have the hierarchy you want without re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @dic19: This was meant as a way to support a "My computer" root object with multiple drives (C:\, D:\, etc.) below it. How could you do that with the standard `DefaultTreeModel` when the "My computer" root does not really exists as a directory and it does not have the drives as its children?

Comment: You can define a "fake" (to name it somehow) root called "My computer" as `DefaultMutableTreeNode`. This will be the root in your `DefaultTreeNode`. Then for each drive create a new `DefaultMutableTreeNode` containing this drive and add them to the root. For each file/folder in each drive create a new `DefaultMutableTreeNode` wrapping the file/folder itself and add them to the appropriate drive node. And so on. It is fairly easy using recursion :-) If you want I could add an example (it won't be soon though, as I'm pretty busy right now)