# Desktop view in JTree - Swing - Windows Only

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtree

I would like to get a desktop view in `JTree`,  something like this:

[image]

I have a [sample code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/FileTreeDemo.htm) which shows only the `c:\`, since I am new to Java, finding difficulties to achieve it.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class FileTreeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File root;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            root = new File(args[0]);
        } else {
            root = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        }

        System.out.println(root);
        FileTreeModel model = new FileTreeModel(root);

        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.setModel(model);
        tree.setRootVisible(true);
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);

        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tree);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileTreeDemo");
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollpane, "Center");
        frame.setSize(400,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);    
    }
}
```

**FileTreeModel class**

```
class FileTreeModel implements TreeModel {

    protected File root;

    public FileTreeModel(File root) { this.root = root; }

    public Object getRoot() { return root; }

    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {  return ((File)node).isFile(); }

    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
        String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
        if (children == null) return 0;
        return children.length;
    }

    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
        if ((children == null) || (index >= children.length)) return null;
        return new File((File) parent, children[index]);
    }

    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
        if (children == null) return -1;
        String childname = ((File)child).getName();
        for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            if (childname.equals(children[i])) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newvalue) {}

    public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}
    public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}
}
```

SO far I have tried to change 'System Properties' but it didn't work:

```
"user.dir"
```

Please show me show me some directions, thanks.

Comment: See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then you need to use [FileSystemView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html) class in order to get OS specific data such as root partitions. Since the JDK1.1 `File` API doesn't allow access OS related information.

Note: in Windows `Desktop` folder is considered a root node. For example, running on Windows the following snippet should print the folders that you see in your desktop, pretty much like the picture you've included:

```
FileSystemView fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
for (File file : fileSystemView.getRoots()) {
    System.out.println("Root: " + file);
    for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Child: " + f);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the following methods to set the correct icon for each node:

- [isComputerNode(File file)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#isComputerNode-java.io.File-)
- [isDrive(File file)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#isDrive-java.io.File-)
- [isFloppyDrive(File file)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#isFloppyDrive-java.io.File-)
- [isFileSystem(File file)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#isFileSystem-java.io.File-)

Comment: Very nice, it looks like this method and the "C:\Users[username]\Desktop" & "C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop" folders are actually complementary: on my laptop these three routes give you almost the entire contents of the Desktop folder. The only two that are missing for me are "Control Panel" and "Recycle Bin".

Comment: Thanks Guys, I got all I wanted in the [list](http://i.imgur.com/NK0COAh.png), thank you so much guys for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Windows Desktop "special folder" (see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder)) is a combination of several folders, like "C:\Users[username]\Desktop" and "C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop". To combine more than one folder in a tree node, you would need a custom tree model like the one discussed in [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041955/set-jtree-in-one-java-class-file-from-second-java-class-file-swing).

Comment: I'm tempted to up-vote your answer for considering public desktop folder. However it is very OS-specific and any Java application is supposed to be platform-independent and that's why I'm reluctant to do so. On the other hand I've upvoted your multi-root suggestion in the earlier question :-)

Comment: Yes, the question should probably be tagged as Windows-only. For OS X and Linux you would probably take a completely different approach.